# Angular 2 this.router.navigate is not working

Tags: angular

Actually I am trying to navigate from main Component to login Component after two database request(post and put). Its not working.

```
constructor(private service:Service, private router:Router){}

select(solution:string, size:string) {
    let obj1 = {};
    let obj2 = {}

    this.service
      .newObj(obj1)
      .subscribe(
        (data) => {this.service.status(obj2, data._id).subscribe((data) =>**this.router.navigate(['/login'])**);
          console.log('data.id', data._id)},
        error => console.log('Could not post data.'));
  }
```

Comment: what error are u getting?

Comment: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

Comment: 3333/node_modules/rxjs/observable/from.js

Comment: Can you share your routing module?

Comment: I dont have routing module. Because I am upgrading from angular 1.x to 2.

Answer (score 4):

I think that you intended to navigate through a URL segment, **'login'**, then you should use `navigateByUrl` instead:

```
this.router.navigateByUrl('/login')
```